# Get original commit info from Merged commit

Tags: git, git-merge, jgit

I have been looking at the log command for an entire day now and I cant still figure out how to get commit hash of the original commits that were merged in an a merge operation.

(That might sound cryptic)

What I am trying to figure out is, when I merge 3 commits from Branch 1 (with commit has aaaa, bbbb, cccc) to master (or anyother branch. And not using fast forward) I get a new commit with hash xyz. Now using xyz how can I find which commits were merged as part of the operation. (Details similar to what svn merge-info would give)

And is it possible to get this information via jGit

---

**Clarification**

Following example should explain the problem I am trying to solve. (Example taken from Answer from chepner below)

**Scenario 1:**

```
[Master] ---ma1 --- ma2 --- ma3 --- merg1 ---
              \                     /
               \                   /
[Branch]        br1 --- br2 --- br3
```

Now using sha merg1, I need to find out what all revisions were merged here. i.e. br1, br2 & br3

**Scenario 2: Same as above but using forks**

```
[Master]      ---ma1 --- ma2 --- ma3 --- merg1 ---
                                         /
                                        /
[fork master]        fr1 --- fr2 --- fr3
```

Now using sha merg1, I need to find out what all revisions were merged here. i.e. fr1, fr2 & fr3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had something like this before the merge:

```
w---x---y---z (master)

aaaa---bbbb---cccc  (somebranch)
```

then running `git merge somebranch` (with `master` as the current branch) produces

```
  w---x---y---z---xyz (master)
                 /
aaaa---bbbb---cccc (somebranch)
```

You can use `^` notation to reference specific parents.

- `master^1` = z
- `master^2` = cccc
- `master^2^` = bbbb

`^1` indicates the first parent (the commit from the branch that was checked out at the time of the merge) and `^2` indicates the second parent (the commit from the branch being merged). A bare `^` is the same as `^1`. The last example shows how they stack; if `master^2` is the second parent of `master`, then `master^2^` is the first parent of `master^2`.

---

Based on your clarification, you are looking for `show-branch` command. Suppose `MB` in the diagram below is the merge base, the last common ancestor between `master` and `somebranch`.

```
...---MB---w---x---y---z---xyz (master)
       \                  /
        aaaa---bbbb---cccc (somebranch)
```

To get the three commits that are unique to `somebranch`, use

```
git show-branch --topics master^1 master^2
```

The `--topics` option omits commits that are reachable from the first commit. Use the `--sha1-name` option to see the (abbreviated) hash for each commit instead of the name relative to `master^2`.

This might give you more output than you want. I'm not sure if there is a way to restrict the output to *just* the commit hashes.

Comment: What I am after is getting revision aaaa, bbbb & cccc from revision xyz. Is that possible in Git?

Comment: @chepner Perhaps use something more basic like `git log MERGE_SHA^1 MERGE_SHA^2`. One can then manipulate the git log options to just show the sha only or whatever format is needed

Comment: @ThongKuah Good point. I wonder if `show-branch` is something that `git log` uses to help build its output.

Comment: @chepner Cool. Does this work if somebranch in this example is Master from a forked repository and was merged back to main repo using Pull Request?